# VS 2013 Run StyleCop Option

Tags: visual-studio-2013, stylecop

I have enabled StyleCop in VS2013 using following steps

1. Installed StyleCop with command `install-package stylecop.msbuild`
2. Updated below lines in .csproj file

   a. `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> 
     <Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />`

   b. `<StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings> in first <PropertyGroup> of the .csproj file.`
3. Copy Settings.StyleCop in the project solution folder from C:\Program Files\StyleCop 4.7 on solution root folder or add as a solution item.
4. Double click the Settings.StyleCop file as configure the rules. You should be able to use the stylecops in your project.

When I build the application, StyleCop functionality is working as expected.
But when I right click on any project I don't see the option "Run StyleCop" or "Run StyleCop (Rescan All).

Can anybody help me on this ?

Comment: I just install it from http://stylecop.codeplex.com and it sets itself up perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/) `StyleCop.MSBuild` simplifies the adding of the properties to a csproj required to run StyleCop as part of the build. It also references a StyleCop instance inside `/packages/` which means that it is downloaded from sourcecontrol and each developer does not need StyleCop installed.

To get the context menus, you need to install [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) on your local machine.